# Generic Add Method in Entity Framework -- Trouble Passing-in Type from String Name

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, generics, variable-types

I admit that a large part of my trouble with this must stem from simple lack of understanding around a few of the components involved in the solution. I'm not exactly "new to" Entity Framework, code-first, nor generic types, but the inner workings of all three are still mysterious enough to me that this is giving me fits.

I have a **code-first** project in which I have separated-out "model" classes from "service" classes, with generalizations in both. I am **NOT** using the full **Repository Pattern**, for a variety of reasons. For most of what I am doing, the structure I have in place is working beautifully -- I understand it and it seems quite clean.

But there is one area where I am running into problems, and that is being able to pass one of my model class types as a generic parameter to an instance of a generic service object, given a string path/name of the model class.

*(Background: I need to do this because I "seed" several tables in the database with initialization values from a JSON file. This JSON file contains the names of the model entities. So, at runtime, I need to get that string value, and then feed that as the type to the generic service object that does the database operations.)*

Here are the pertinent code snippets:

In **BaseEntity.cs** I have the top-level interface and a number of abstract classes from which the specific model entities then inherit:

```
namespace POST.API.Models
{
    public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class BaseEntity { }

    public abstract class Entity : BaseEntity, IEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class TypeEntity : Entity
    {
        public TypeDefinition Definition { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In **BaseService.cs** I have another interface and more abstract classes from which specific model service classes inherit. There is also one concrete class, here, that is generalized for performing an insert operation:

```
namespace POST.API.Services
{
    public interface IEntityService { }

    public abstract class BaseEntityService<T> : IEntityService
        where T : Models.BaseEntity
    {
        public T Fetch(int Id)
        {
            using (var Db = new PostDbContext())
            {
                return Db.Set<T>().Find(Id);
            }
        }

        public void Create(T Item)
        {
            if (Item != null)
            {
                using (var Db = new PostDbContext())
                {
                    DbSet Entity = Db.Set<T>();

                    Entity.Add(Item);
                    Db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> All()
        {
            using (var Db = new PostDbContext())
            {
                return (IEnumerable<T>)Db.Set<T>().ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseTypeEntityService<T> : BaseEntityService<T>
        where T : Models.TypeEntity
    { }

    public abstract class BasePropertyTypeEntityService<T> : BaseTypeEntityService<T>
        where T : Models.PropertyTypeEntity { }

    public abstract class BasePropertyEntityService<T> : BaseEntityService<T>
        where T : Models.BaseEntity { }

    public class TypeEntityService<T> : BaseTypeEntityService<T>
        where T : Models.TypeEntity { }

    #endregion
}
```

I've removed some methods not pertinent to the presentation.

I have some code that then attempts to use these base classes to rummage through the JSON file and insert some rows, thus:

```
        using (PostDbContext Db = new PostDbContext())
        {
            string JsonString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(JsonDataFile);
            DataSet JsonDataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(JsonString);
            foreach (DataTable Table in JsonDataSet.Tables)
            {
                Type EType = Type.GetType("POST.API.Models." + Table.TableName);
                POST.API.Models.BaseEntity E = (POST.API.Models.BaseEntity)Activator.CreateInstance(EType);
                Services.TypeEntityService<EType> S = new Services.TypeEntityService<EType>();

                foreach (DataRow Row in Table.Rows)
                {
                    // Set properties of E and call Create method of S
                }
            }
        }
```

I've clearly misunderstood something fundamental, because that code won't compile. On this line of code:

```
Services.TypeEntityService<EType> S = new Services.TypeEntityService<EType>();
```

...I get an error on my references to EType, with the compiler complaining **"The type or namespace `EType' could not be found."**

So, obviously, that reference, there, cannot be evaluated at runtime. Which, then, makes me wonder how on earth do I do this. All the related topics seem to yield no satisfactory answer -- at least not in a way that makes sense in the context of my own implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `Services.TypeEntityService<EType>` with the Activator, something like below...

```
            Type EType = Type.GetType("POST.API.Models." + Table.TableName);
            Type[] typeArgs = { EType };
            var generic = typeof(Services.TypeEntityService<>).MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
            var S = Activator.CreateInstance(generic);
```

Comment: Okay... This does make more sense to me, in some respects, and does indeed solve one problem. However I still cannot reference properties & methods of the E and S variables, which is the whole point... I.e., I can't actually set the properties of E and then call the Create method of S, in order to add a new E...

Comment: I didnt include the code to create the E, but from there you will need to use reflection to call the method from `var method = S.GetMethod("MyMethodName");` and then `var result = method.Invoke(generic , new object[] { E });`

Comment: Except that S does not have GetMethod available, at least in the way the code is present structured... S only has Equals, GetType, GetHashCode, and ToString available, as a var...

Comment: Sorry about that, try `var method = typeof(Services.TypeEntityService<>).GetMethod("MyMethodName");`

Comment: Okay, yes, that's getting me there. This is all looking somewhat familiar, but I honestly don't use reflection all that much and it's making my brain hurt... So how then do I set the set the properties of E? I imagine it's similar... GetPropery or some such?

Comment: You should be able to set E similar to your original code `POST.API.Models.BaseEntity E = (POST.API.Models.BaseEntity)Activator.CreateInstance(EType);` then E.PropertyName = "value";`

Comment: Sorry, it's wanting me to switch to chat... One more observation, however: in the way I've invoked it, and as you suggest above, E does not have the properties available in that way. Looks like I have to `var property = typeof(Models.BaseEntity).GetProperty("property");`

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` returns `object` which is why you don't see anything other than the base `object` methods in your intellisense. You could cast to one of the base, non generic types or interfaces but you'd lose any methods or properties from the more derived classes. Or you could have a big chain of if statements doing type checks. No good way without reflection which can get ugly if you don't know what you're doing. You could always use `dynamic` instead but then it's up to the DLR and you'd still not have intellisense but it'd compile.

Comment: Thanks. I marked this as this as the solution as what you presented did, essentially, provide me with an answer to my initial question. The overall sense I'm getting, though, is that this is one of those problems for which there really is no fundamentally slick/elegant solution. Every approach has a certain ugliness and needless complexity to it. I'm fortunate in that none of the model classes I'm trying to add are implemented in any way that differs from the base. They all have the same properties.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a variabl of type `System.Type` in `EType`. You cannot use Type instances for generic types. You shouldchange your implementation of `Services.TypeEntityService` to take runtime Type instances (e.g TypeEntityService(System.Type type)).

Edit: Or actually like the other answer states, use Reflection to build Generic parameters from your Type instance. That makes more sense.